# Dagger using dynamic data

Tags: android, dagger

I have DI in my project. One of modules is `AppModule` and he is providing `RestClient`

```
@WithoutAuth
@Provides
@Singleton
RestAdapter provideRestAdapter(final RemontnikPreferences preferences) {

    final String userAndPassword = preferences.getUsername() + ":" + preferences.getPassword();
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userAndPassword.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    };
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://")
            .setRequestInterceptor(
            .build();
    preferences.setPassword("");
    return restAdapter;
}
```

On the login fragment I enter my username and password, they saves into `SharedPreferences` all seems be good. Authorization works.

But if i enter wrong credentials, they saves into shared preferences, but when i'm re-enter valid credentials my `RestClient` doesnt updating, because `AppModule` instantiate only once when the application starts. How can i re-create `AppModule` to use new shared preferences?

Comment: The simplest solution is to remove `@Singleton`, but a new instance will be created each time you request this dependency.

Comment: @tomrozb
But i request dependency only once in my class...
How i can manually update dependency when it need.

Comment: You can't. You have to create a new instance of the class to reinject its dependencies.

Comment: You could also put code about forming header inside `intercept` method. You can cache value and re-calculate it when shared preferences are changed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the `userAndPassword` string when you create the adapter.

```
@WithoutAuth
@Provides
@Singleton
RestAdapter provideRestAdapter(final RemontnikPreferences preferences) {
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            String userAndPassword = preferences.getUsername() + ":" + preferences.getPassword();
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userAndPassword.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    };
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://")
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();
    preferences.setPassword("");
    return restAdapter;
}
```

Then each time a request is created,  and the interceptor is called, it will check preferences and pull in the values it needs.